# Equivalent to systemd timers on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, daemons

On Linux, many distros ship with systemd. Systemd supports "timers", which are a kind of systemd service for running programs on a schedule. There are of course many ways of scheduling tasks, such as the venerable cron which was replaced by systemd. However, the benefits of systemd specifically are:

- CLI with convenient commands to enable, disable and check the status of timers
- Each scheduled task is entirely defined in a single text file
- The timer syntax is very extensive with ways to cover different types of exceptional situations and corner cases

Is there a similar way of scheduling tasks in OS X? I am interested primarily in running command line programs and scripts, so GUI support is not important to me.

Comment: launchd is the mac equivalent.

Comment: _As a side note:_ OS X is already dated name of the Apple desktop operating system. Since 2016, specifically since the version 10.12 (macOS Sierra) it is officially called [**macOS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On Linux, many distros ship with systemd. Systemd supports "timers", which are a kind of systemd service for running programs on a schedule... Is there a similar way of scheduling tasks in OS X?

#### It’s called [`launchd`](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/script-management-with-launchd-apdc6c1077b-5d5d-4d35-9c19-60f2397b2369/mac).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd):

> launchd is an init and operating system service management daemon created by Apple Inc. as part of macOS to replace its BSD-style init and SystemStarter. There have been efforts to port launchd to FreeBSD and derived systems

#### Additional Resources

- [launchd plist format for running a command at a specific time on a weekday](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249446/119271)
- [Is there a way to make login items only work on specific days?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454309/119271)
- [Scheduling Timed Jobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2) (Apple Developer)
- [A Launchd Tutorial](https://launchd.info/)

Comment: It looks like the scheduling is explained in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2

Comment: Thanks!  I added that to the answer!

Comment: Also useful to read the related manual pages: `man launchd` and `man launchctl`.